# How to convert numbers like 1e+10, 5e-6 and so on to the form 10^10, 5 * 10^-6?

Tags: javascript

I have a calculator that outputs values ​​and converts them to an exponent using the **toExponential()** function.
But now I want these numbers to take on a more "human-readable" form.
I tried to do it with array iteration but I doubt my solution is correct

In the array, I get several dozen elements that look like ['1', '+6'], ['5', '-12']. I separated them by the character "e"

The result is displayed in the table as a string

Right now I managed to change all units to 10
But I still need to know the math operator and other numbers other than one

```
convertToHumanReadableNumber(num) {
      let arr = []
      arr.push(num.split('e'))
      let arr2 = arr.map(el => {
        if (el[0] == '1') {
          return el[0] = '10'   
         }
      })
    }
```

Comment: You've overcomplicated the task. The array you need is just a splitted `num`, then use the members, at `0` there's the mantissa, at `1` you can find the exponent. Use those values to create a simple string.